# Can't place order for ad because of "Cannot change og_type" to "website"

Tags: ads, facebook-ads-api

Every time I try and place an ad i get "Cannot change og_type: The object at .... previously had type 'object' and cannot be changed to an object of type 'website' to avoid data corruption of existing actions."

I have read a developer blog post by facebook saying you can now change your object types but there is no documentation anywhere on how to do it. I know you have a certain amount of likes until you are not allowed to change the value but I have < than 100 right now.

I've seen other posts saying you can change the og:type somehow but changing the tags in my site does nothing and I don't see any detailed instructions of another way anywhere on the web.

Comment: How are you trying to place the ad? Are you actually using the ads api? Also, what type of ad are you trying to create?

Comment: I am trying to make one at http://www.facebook.com/ads/create/ .  I am trying to place an ad for a mobile app I created.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can get Facebook to refresh it's copy of metadata by running the link through the URL Debug tool: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

If the issue isn't resolved, pls file a bug with repro parameters through http://developers.facebook.com/bugs and tag it as ads api and our support team will be happy to assist.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried the debug tool to death, it doesn't seem to make a difference.  I came to post this response here because I filed a bug for this at facebook.com/bugs and they told me it wasnt a bug and sent me here!  http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/149148871943847